# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using BGL graph

Tags: boost, stl, graphviz, omnet++

I am trying to implement Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm using BGL libraries in OMNET++

In course of doing so, I came across we need Graphviz DOT file for the same.

How do I create DOT file for the algorithm using graphviz?

Answer (score 0):

You can create DOT files by hand pretty easily. The file format is fairly simple and documented on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) and on the graphviz [website](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html).

Here's a sample of a simple acyclic directed graph.

```
digraph graph-name {
     a -> b -> c;
     b -> d;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Flinn,

I got the code for Dijkstra from Graphviz manual, but the code is not compiling.

I am trying to implement Dijkstra in BGL using graphviz, example given in User Guide and reference manual http://www.mail-archive.com/boost@lists.boost.org/msg10259.html

The code is giving syntax error, at the line

using namespace boost;
GraphvizDigraph g_dot; ' read_graphviz("figs/ospf-graph.dot", g_dot);'

How do I proceed ?